# How to connect a shape and a path in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, shapes

I'm trying to connect these two but I can't figure it out. I want the left shape to continue it's line and have it's curvature and naturally connect to the right side.

[image]

This is a rough example of the output I'm looking for:

[image]

How many ways are there for me to do this?

EDIT: It's ok if they can't be technically connect but look like they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to *expand* the stroke to join it to a shape. You can not join stroked paths with shapes. You can only combine shapes with shapes.

---

Start with the shape and stroke....

[image]

Line them up....

[image]

Select *only the stroked path portion* and choose `Object > Expand`from the menu.. and then simply hit the `OK` button for the pop up dialog window. This will convert the stroked path to a *filled shape* which can then be joined with the existing shape.

[image]

Select *both* objects and then grab the **Shape Builder Tool**. Click-drag with the **Shape Builder Tool** across both shapes to combine them....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't technically.

Shapes and paths are two different concepts in Illustrator and you cannot combine a square with a line for instance. Even if your square looks like a normal line, it is not a line and you can't edit a line-looking shape like you edit a normal path (line).

This can only work if **both** objects are either shape or line. In your case specifically, you need to manually redraw the ornament shape on the left using paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly because the shape is a closed path, but the line is just a stroke.

A workaround is to convert the stroke to outlines first by doing *Object > Expand*, to turn it into a closed path. Then move it to overlap your shape, select both shapes, and in the Pathfinder, hit the Unite button.

Comment: The `Object > Expand` solution is interesting and it works on one side. but if I want to do it on the other side ( which I didn't show in the screenshot ) everything inside the expanded line becomes filled with black.

Comment: @xperator - it would depend on how the part we can't see is constructed. Is it a stroke or is it already a closed path?  Expanding a stroke will fill it in - i.e. it will become a filled shape.