# How can I make these 2 shapes join smoothly?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I draw a curve and then draw a rectangle below it. The curve stroke is 6, and the rectangle stroke is 3. I cannot move the rectangle to match the curve. It always has a little bit of a gap.

How can i join them to form a single object (path) ?

[image: line cannot be join perfectly]

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/130048/how-to-connect-a-shape-and-a-path-in-illustrator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting them to line up is easy enough since one stroke is exactly half the width of the other.

1. Make sure Smart Guides are switched on
2. Open the a Transform dialog and set the options as shown below
3. Select the rectangle, and in the Stroke panel set "align stroke to outside"

[image]

4. Click and drag the corner until the Smart Guide shows them aligned, and do the same for the other side of the rectangle

[image]

5. To join both objects as one, you can expand the strokes and join both with the pathfinder to get one object. However the strokes will no longer be editable as strokes - they will become a filled shape instead.

[image]